# Print occurence count of "keys" and sum of the associated "values" in 3-column data file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I’m reading a Redis dump file using shell.

There are 3 main columns in the dump file as below.

```
Text:tags:name    682651    520
Text:tags:age     78262     450
Value:cache       77272     672
Value:cache:name  76258     872
New:specific      77628     762
New:test          76628     8622
```

Expected output:

```
Key     Count     Sum
Text:*  2         970
Value:* 2         1544
New:*   2         9384
```

Looking to get the expected above as columns can be checked based on substrings may be staring/middle/ending with strings (keys).

Comment: Welcome to U&L, what have you tried so far Dilip ?

Comment: Also, please explain the input format in more detail (most contributors will not now immediately what a "Redis dump" is): Are the input columns space- or tab-separated? Do you want the output space- or tab-separated? Can there be empty lines/comment lines in the input? And, as @steve already mentioned, what did you try, and where did you face problems you need help with?

Comment: So no need to process the column starting `682651 ... .` ? Are you able to handle that yourself, and possibly post a cleaner 'Sample Input' ?

Comment: If you found any of the answers useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` program will perform the task:

```
awk '{split($1,f,/:/);count[f[1]]++;sum[f[1]]+=$3}
     END{printf "Key\tCount\tSum\n"; for (k in count) {printf "%s:*\t%d\t%d\n",k,count[k],sum[k]}}' dump.txt
```

- This will first split the keys at column 1 at the `:` into components which are then stored in an array `f`. The first entry (`f[1]`) is taken as the relevant key for all further processing.
- The occurence count will be stored in an associative array `count`, taking the key `f[1]` as array index. It will simply be increased by 1 every time the key is found.
- The sum of the values in column 3 is stored similarly in an associative array `sum`.
- In the end, the program prints the header line and then iterates over all array indices found in the array `count` to print the array index (= the key), the occurence counts and the summed values.

Note that the order in which the keys are printed is defined by the internal logic in which `awk` stores arrays. If you have GNU Awk, you can set the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` property in a `BEGIN` section to define the traversing order. For example

```
BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}
```

would make `awk` print the entries in ascending lexicographical order of the "keys".

Answer (score 0):

First modify the first field so that everything after the first `:` is replaced by a `*`:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ sub(":.*", ":*", $1) }; 1' file
```

This `awk` command modifies the first whitespace-delimited field by replacing the first match of the extended regular expression `:.*` with the literal string `:*`.  The output of this, given your data, will be the following tab-delimited data:

```
Text:*  682651  520
Text:*  78262   450
Value:* 77272   672
Value:* 76258   872
New:*   77628   762
New:*   76628   8622
```

We may then group this by the first tab-delimited field while counting how many lines are collapsed into each group and summing the third field.  One way to do this is by using GNU `datamash`:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ sub(":.*", ":*", $1) }; 1' file |
datamash groupby 1 count 1 sum 3
```

If the original input is unsorted, then either pass the data from `awk` through `sort` or use `datamash` with its `-s` option.

This would output the following (which is tab-delimited):

```
Text:*  2       970
Value:* 2       1544
New:*   2       9384
```

To output the headers, simply first invoke

```bash
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' 'Key' 'Count' 'Sum'
```

The complete thing, reading from `file` and writing to some new file `output`:

```bash
{
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' 'Key' 'Count' 'Sum'
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{ sub(":.*", ":*", $1) }; 1' |
    datamash groupby 1 count 1 sum 3
} <file >output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[:[:space:]]+' '
    { cnt[$1]++; sum[$1]+=$NF }
    END {
        print "Key", "Count", "Sum"
        for (key in cnt) {
            print key":*", cnt[key], sum[key]
        }
    }
' file | column -t
Key      Count  Sum
Value:*  2      1544
Text:*   2      970
New:*    2      9384
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my (@k, @v); given lines.map(*.words).list {  \
            @k = .map(*.[0].split(":").[0]); @v = .map(*.[2]) };  \
            my %count1 = Bag(@k); my %agg1.=append: [Z=>] @k, @v;  \
            my %sum1; for %agg1 { %sum1.append: $_.key => [+] $_.value };  \
            for ([Z] %count1.sort, %sum1.sort) {  \
            say .[0].key ~qb[\t]~ .[0].value ~qb[\t]~ .[1].value};' file
```

Sample Input:

```
Text:tags:name    682651    520
Text:tags:age     78262     450
Value:cache       77272     672
Value:cache:name  76258     872
New:specific      77628     762
New:test          76628     8622
```

Sample Output:

```
New     2   9384
Text    2   970
Value   2   1544
```

This solution utilizes hash functionalities present in all Perl-family languages, here specifically written in Raku.

Briefly, `lines` are read in, and each line is broken into whitespace-separated `words` (`map` is what instructs Raku to work within 'each' line element). The data is saved into `@k` array containing the first string element after `split`ting on colons, and `@v` array which just contains the 3rd column (zero-index = 2). At this point the arrays  look like so:

```perl
#Add this statement:
.say for @k, @v;

#Returns:
[Text Text Value Value New New]
[520 450 672 872 762 8622]
```

Raku has a `Bag()` function built-in, which gives the occurrences (counts) of each of the keys  (using the line `my %count1 = Bag(@k);`).

From here an aggregate `%agg1` hash is created, that "zips" down the `@k` and `@v` columns, `=>` pairing them together, and `append`ing them into the `%agg1` hash. Of course a property of hashes is that every `key` is unique, thus `values` associated with the same `key` are placed as array elements constituting each key's `value`. At this point the `%agg1` hash looks like so:

```perl
#Add this statement:
.say for %agg1.sort;

#Returns:
New => [762 8622]
Text => [520 450]
Value => [672 872]
```

The `%agg1` hash is then iterated over again to create the `%sum1` hash, which (you guessed it) sums the individual `values` in a `key`-wise manner. Finally, data is output, separated by tabs (the `~qb[\t]~` quotes the `\t` tab reducing the need for double-quotes within the code), and string concatenation is accomplished via `~` tilde.

https://andrewshitov.com/2020/03/16/a-couple-of-syntax-sweets-in-raku/
https://youtu.be/wViVLytlwb8
https://raku.org